# Show ChartJS on ngIf Condition in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, angular-material

I'm using ChartJS with Angular Material and I'm trying to show the chart on condition using a localStorage object.

Right now I have the local storage object set to ChartData and I'm trying to have the chart show on condition for ChartData.DataPoints which is a value in the ChartData object.

For some reason I am getting a

> Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

error. I want to have it where if ChartData.Datapoints has any values in the array then the chart will show, if not then it is hidden. How do I do this?

**view.component.html**

```
    <!-- Charts -->
    <mat-card *ngIf="ChartData.DataPoints">
      <canvas id="viewChart"></canvas>
  </mat-card>
```

**view.component.ts**

```
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

viewData: any;
viewName: string;
viewTag: number;
pageIndex: number;
pageSize: number;
sortCol: string;
sortDirection: string;
filter: ViewFilter;
loadType: string;

FunctionNames: string[];
ChartData: any;
FunctionsActive: boolean[];

fetchedData: any;
action: ViewDataSource;
dataSource: ViewDataSource;
pageSizeOptions: number[] = [10, 20, 50];

contextMenuPosition = { x: '0 px', y: '0 px'};

@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) contextMenu: MatMenuTrigger;

navSub: Subscription;

selection = new SelectionModel<TableRow>(true, []);
primaryTableValue: any;
selectedIndexData: ViewDataSource;


canvas: any;
ctx: any;
ChartLegend: any;

constructor(private actionService: ActionService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public dialog: MatDialog,
  private launchService: LaunchService) {

    // Init these two fields on a dummy ViewData so that the mat-table does not throw errors.
    this.viewData = {
        ColumnObjects: new Array(),
        ViewData: {
            DataRows: new Array()
        }
    };
}

ngOnInit() {

    // Init the dataSource
    this.dataSource = new ViewDataSource(this.actionService);

    // Init the component the first time it is navigated to.
    this.initData();

    // Subscribe to the router, so that any new navigation to this component loads new data.
    this.navSub = this.router.events.subscribe((e: any) => {
        if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.initData();
        }
    });



    // Subscribe to the View in the DataSource

    this.dataSource.view.subscribe(x => {
        if (x.ActionName) {
            this.viewName = x.ActionName;
            this.viewData = x;
            this.fetchedData = this.viewData.TableData;
            console.log(this.viewData);

            this.primaryTableValue = (this.viewData.ViewData.DbrAction.PrimaryTable);
        }
    });

    // Charts

    this.canvas = document.getElementById('viewChart');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.ChartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ChartData'));

    const data = this.ChartData;

    // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
    const driverLabel = data.map(function (e: any[]) {
        return e[1];
      });

    // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
      const firstDataPoint = data.map(function (e: any[]) {
        return e[3];
      });

    // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
      const secondDataPoint = data.map(function (e: any[]) {
        return e[4];
      });

     // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
      const thirdDataPoint = data.map(function (e: any[]) {
        return e[5];
      });

    const viewChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: driverLabel,
            datasets: [
                {
                label: 'Plan Miles',
                data: firstDataPoint,
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
                label: 'Actual Miles',
                data: secondDataPoint,
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
                label: 'Route Variance',
                data: thirdDataPoint,
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById('viewChart') is null until this.ChartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ChartData')); is resolved try spliting this logic int ngOnInit and ngAfterContentInit

Comment: I’m a little confused you mean it’ll be two OnInit? @Xesenix

Comment: one part of init should be done after you get correct value for document.getElementById('viewChart') which will be available after view will render template. You will need to check if its actualy not null

Comment: yeah it's null until after onInit is ran

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: yeah I did the ngAfterContentInit but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: you need to add guard against null value because there will be time when this.ChartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ChartData')); will be empty and document.getElementById('viewChart') will be empty even after init

Comment: how would I do that? does that go in the html template or where in the component? @Xesenix

Comment: `if (this.canvas !== null)` araoud anything that relays on this value or any other that can be null

Comment: wouldn't that be the entire chart? i'm confused.. @Xesenix

Comment: you should run chart initialization only if you have all initial conditions needed for the chart to be displayed fulfilled there are many ways to achieve this I personally would use observable to collect all necessary data and just after that run initialization logic for charts remebering about cleaning up if condition change or component is removed. But you can try just removing ngIf that should make life easier for you as that would make document.getElementById('viewChart') exist most of time. Another way would be to use https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild for canvas

Comment: i don't get it i'm totally loss... why and where can I use the ngIf? I need to use ngIf because that's how I'm switching between a chart view and a datatable

Comment: you probably should have some component that encapsulates chart and then you can have ngIf on top of that component this way if ngIf allows to render that part of view initialization logic inside this chart component will know when to run and render chart and when its turrned of there should be ngOnDestroy that cleans memory from chart related variables

Comment: I'm lost I did that but i'm still getting the same error @Xensenix

Comment: can you create stackblitz example for it?